# Replicating colab env in conda

Tags: python, opencv, keras, conda, environment

I would like to replicate/install this colab environment on conda

```
cv2 Version = 4.1.2  Keras Version = 2.4.3  Python 3.6.9
```

when i try

```
conda create --name opencv -c conda-forge  python=3.6.9 opencv=4.1.2 keras=2.4.3
```

i get a lot of conflicts, how can i fix it?

```
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.6.9 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a']
python=3.6.9 -> pypy3.6=7.3.2 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1f,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a']

Package numpy conflicts for:
keras=2.4.3 -> numpy[version='>=1.9.1']
opencv=4.1.2 -> py-opencv==4.1.2=py38h5ca1d4c_2 -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0']
keras=2.4.3 -> h5py -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*|1.12.*|1.13.*|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|>=1.8|>=1.8,<1.14|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.9|>=1.11|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0|>=1.13.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.1|>=1.13.3|>=1.12.1|>=1.11.0|>=1.8.2|>=1.10.1']

Package tk conflicts for:
keras=2.4.3 -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> tk[version='8.5.*|8.6.*|>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.9,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0']
python=3.6.9 -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']

Package ncurses conflicts for:
python=3.6.9 -> pypy3.6=7.3.2 -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
python=3.6.9 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0']

Package xz conflicts for:
python=3.6.9 -> pypy3.6=7.3.2 -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<5.3.0a0']
python=3.6.9 -> xz[version='>=5.2.4,<5.3.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']

Package python conflicts for:
keras=2.4.3 -> python[version='>=3.6']
python=3.6.9
keras=2.4.3 -> h5py -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|3.7.*|3.8.*']
opencv=4.1.2 -> py-opencv==4.1.2=py38h5ca1d4c_2 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.6.9 -> pypy3.6=7.3.2 -> sqlite[version='>=3.33.0,<4.0a0']
python=3.6.9 -> sqlite[version='>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0']

Package pypy3.6 conflicts for:
python=3.6.9 -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*']
python=3.6.9 -> python_abi==3.6[build=*_pypy36_pp73] -> pypy3.6=7.3
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Comment: I don't see any legitimate conflicts in the set listed. Did you truncate it? Note that any set that only has dependency chains rooted in one constraint can be ignored. E.g., `openssl`, `ncurses`, `xz`, `sqlite`, `pypy3.6` only have `python` as the root of their constraints, so those can all be skipped.

Comment: I have tried, as you suggested, but the only way to install on my system opencv was via opencv-python, i do not know why

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not fully tested, I installed opencv-python